# How the functions overflow and underflow of basic_streambuf wok

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading the C++ 11 standard. The sections 27.6.3.4.3/7 and 27.6.3.4.5/3 describe the functions "int_type underflow();" and "int_type overflow(int_type c = traits::eof());". There is no example to explain how they work. Can somebody help to explain the functions with the example?

Comment: These functions are used when you make your own streambuf.  The standard provides streambufs attacked to files or strings.  For example, I've made one attached to a listbox, so that any messages written to `cout` or `cerr` end up as list items when a newline character is seen.  And I had to override `overflow()` to make that happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is pretty simple. `underflow` is used for input streams. When there's no data left in the input buffer, `underflow` is called to read data from the actual source (e.g., file or socket) to at least partially refill the buffer.

`overflow` is pretty much the opposite -- when a buffer is full, `overflow` is called to write the data out to the associated file or socket, or whatever. It's also called to flush the buffer just before an output stream is destroyed.

Comment: Best answer! Concise and elegant!